# First order differential eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im stuck on $y' = 1 + y^2, y(0)= 0$
I am really rusty with ode's so im having trouble with this one so
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2\implies \frac{dy}{1+y^2}=dx$$

Integrating $$\arctan y=x+c$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral.

As $y(0)=0, \arctan 0=0+c\implies c=0$ taking the principal value of $\arctan 0$

$\implies \arctan y=x\iff y=\tan x$